# is godaddy SSL standard certificate compatible with *all* browsers?

Tags: ssl-certificate

Could you answer to at least one of these questions:

1) Is godaddy SSL standard certificate compatible with all browsers (chrome and safari on iphone, or android browsers included) ?

http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/ssl-certificates.aspx?ci=8979

2) Is it running on Apache servers ?

Comment: Better ask this on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those particular certs claim to have 99% Browser Recognition.
I think that's pretty high but I have found the Godaddy certs to be pretty good.

Remember they are probably not including mobile browsers in this statistic.

Also have you checked out this page as they are cheaper?

http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/ssl-certificates-verisign.aspx?isc=sslqgica15

Comment: Also check out link i added Patrick. Yes they can run on apache.